# WPF- Combobox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, custom-lists

I have a class named "employee":

```
public string Forname { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public EmployeeGroup Group { get; set; }
```

a class "EmployeeGroup":

```
public string Groupname { get; set; }
public short GroupID { get; set; }
```

and a wpf:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbGroup" SelectedItem="{Binding Group}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtForename" Text="{Binding Forname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="342,21,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" GotFocus="SelectText"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtLastname" Text="{Binding Lastname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="342,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" GotFocus="SelectText"/>
<ListBox x:Name="lstEmployee" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="362" Margin="25,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" SelectionChanged="lstEmployee_SelectionChanged"/>
```

The ComboBox and the ListBox gets the source from the code-behind-file (a ObservableCollection):

```
cmbGroup.ItemsSource = Database_Contract.GetListOfContract();
lstEmployee.ItemsSource = Database_Employee.GetListOfEmployee();
```

And I set the DataContext when an employee is selected in the ListBox in the code-behind-file of the wpf:

```
DataContext = lstEmployee.SelectedItem;
```

The binding with the ListBox and TextBoxes works fine, but I have a problem with the Combobox:
The source works, means that i can select different Groups. But there is no binding to the selected employee. So when I select the employee, the TextBoxes with the fore- and lastname filled right, but the Combobox ist emtpy. But when I click the Combobox, then I can choose from the given Groups.

So what I've done wrong?

Edit:
When I set the Binding of the ComboBox.SelectedIndex to the Group.GroupID, then it works. But it's not guaranteed that the GroupID and the ComboBox-Index is the same.

Comment: In your xaml is a `ComboBox` named cmbGroup and you are setting the `ItemsSource`of a `ComboBox` named cmbContract. That's a bit confusing.

To be sure: the items in your `ComboBox` are the same for every employee and when you select an employee in your `ListBox` you want to select the matching entry in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: As a note, instead of changing the Window's(?) DataContext, you may write your Bindings like `Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Lastname, ElementName=lstEmployee}"`.

Comment: You'll also have to make sure that the Group instance that the SelectedItem property is bound to is actually contained in the ItemsSource collection of the ListBox. If they are different objects, you may override the Equals method of the EmployeeGroup class.

Comment: @Mighty, I've typed it wrong, now its correct

Comment: @ Clemens, I'm pretty sure that it's the same object, but is there a way to verify it?

Comment: @Clemens The same object = the same instance and not another object with the same values; just to be sure.

Comment: You may call `object.ReferenceEquals()` to bypass any potentially overridden `Equals()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...
I've changed to MVVM, set the binding of the cmbGroup to the ListOfGroup, overridden the GetHashCode and Equals methods of the class EmployeeGroup, and it works.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you set the DataContext of the whole view to the selected Employee.
This is effectively changing the binding context of the combo box as well and so all the binding's are changing.

I would suggest you give yourself a SelectedEmployee property in the code and set that in the selectedItemChanged event and then you can change the bindings for your text boxes to read `Text="{Binding SelectedEmployee.Forname}"`

You will probably find that the values won't automatically update on screen when you do this, and this is because you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your form code, and then call OnPropertyChanged from your property setters to tell the bindings to refresh.

Comment: "set the DataContext of the whole view to the selected Employee, this is effectively changing the binding context of the combo box as well and so all the binding's are changing" is not the problem, but exactly what OP wants to do.